# How do you target individual range sliders with CSS

Tags: html, css, rangeslider

I have several range sliders and would like to have a different colour for the "runnable track” on each one. I have given each slider  an individual CLASS (in this case it is sepiaSlider, but can’t find a reference online to the syntax to target that.

All I can think of trying is..

```
<input class="sliders sepiaSlider sepiaSliderID7643108" type="range" name="amountRange" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" oninput="this.form.amountInput.value=this.value">


<style>
.sepiaSlider input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    //styles
 }
</style>
```

...and that doesn’t work.

Could I target it by wrapping the input with a div with the class “sepiaSlider” and then do something like...

```
.sepiaSlider > input{}
```

instead?

Comment: Questions regarding how an element might be selected with CSS require you to show us the (relevant) [mcve] code; otherwise all we can do is guess. For better or worse. As regards your specific question: "*[could] I target it by wrapping...*" then yes, of course you can. Is it the 'best', easiest, most reliable or even the only way? Without your code who knows.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am consistently bad at asking questions, it is something I am working on. I have updated the question.

Comment: You accidentally removed a large part of your question. Please [edit] to correctly do whatever edit you wanted to apply.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to use [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) to control the values you need and you don't have to repeat the CSS of the slider.

Here is an example where I change the background color:

```css
::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: var(--c,yellow);
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
.type1 {
  --c:red;
}
.type2 {
  --c:blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="type1">
<input type="range" class="type2">
<input type="range">
```

Comment: Oh wow, do you have a reference to this “--c” type syntax as I have never seen that before. Thanks!

Comment: @Marley yes here is : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables